# Ubuntu 13.04 can only work in recovery mode

Tags: boot, intel-graphics, 13.04

I have just updated my 12.10 to 13.04. Everything is updated.

But I can only boot to a black screen. I mean after the GRUB interface and purple screen. And I can hear the voice of the password interface. But it is only the black screen. It all works OK in 12.10.

But it can work in the recovery mode. I mean go into the recovery mode and choose resume. And then everything is OK. But when loading kernel, the screen is dirty.

I don't know why and I have Googled a lot. But no resolutions works. My graphics card is Intel GMA HD 4000, tested as VESA: Intel® Sandybridge/Ivybridge Graphics.

I have been trapped in this for a whole day. I do need help. Hope someone can help me.

By the way, the kernel is 3.8.0-19 if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

It looks I've solved this issue by adding "nomodeset" param to the grub settings. More info can be found here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Answer (score 0):

Same story here, except after entering recovery menu I choose "boot with network support" - this mounts my drives and tries to start some networking. This makes screen output some text and freeze. But right after pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the normal login screen appears. I have some nvidia graphics card and it looks like my video drivers are ok.